# Redis create client always connecting to 127.0.0.1 even if i specifically change the redis host ip

Tags: javascript, docker, express, docker-compose, redis

I'm having a issue trying to connect my app container to the redis container.

Keep getting the same error -> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

But this only happens if I run both in a docker container. If I try to run only redis in a container and my app locally all seems to be working fine.

Here is part of my .js code that connects to redis:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userService = require('../service/userService')
const constants = require('../helpers/constants')
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis');
client.connect();


var checkCache = async (req, res, next) => {
    
    const data = await client.get('get-users');
    if(!data){
        next();
    }else{
        client.disconnect();
        return res.status(200).json(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  };


router.get('/users', checkCache, async function (req, res) {
    const users = await userService.getUser();
    client.set('get-users', JSON.stringify(users));
    client.expire('get-users', 60);
    client.disconnect();
    return res.status(200).json(users)

});
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: "redis"
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      node_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.4
    volumes:
      - $PWD/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
  market:
    tty: true
    container_name: "market_place"
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      node_net:
        ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5
    ports:
      - "${MF_PORT:-4000}:4000"
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
networks:
  node_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

The error I get after building and starting my container is the following:

```
Listening in port 4000
market_place | node:internal/process/promises:246
market_place |           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
market_place |           ^
market_place | 
market_place | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
market_place |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16)
market_place | Emitted 'error' event on Commander instance at:
market_place |     at RedisSocket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:332:14)
market_place |     at RedisSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
market_place |     at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_retryConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:146:14)
market_place |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
market_place |     at async RedisSocket._RedisSocket_connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:113:55)
market_place |     at async Commander.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:156:9) {
market_place |   errno: -111,
market_place |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
market_place |   syscall: 'connect',
market_place |   address: '127.0.0.1',
market_place |   port: 6379
market_place | }
market_place | npm notice 
market_place | npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.1.2 -> 8.3.0
market_place | npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.3.0
market_place | npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.3.0 to update!
market_place | npm notice
```

Can somebody explain why it's trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 even though my container ip is 172.28.1.4?

If i remove the network configuration on the docker compose and run my code locally, I'm able to connect and save everything in the redis database.

I've already checked some other questions here posted but none of them asked and resolved my problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not provide the IP of the Redis container when creating the client. Try this:

```js
// const client = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis');
const client = redis.createClient({
  socket: {
    port: 6379,
    host: '172.28.1.4',
  }
});
```

Check [`createClient` configuration](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/HEAD/docs/client-configuration.md) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eranga Heshan. I edited the code with what you suggested and it worked.

Comment: You can use the Compose service name `redis` as a host name, instead of manually configuring IP addresses; see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  You could significantly simplify the Compose setup by deleting the unnecessary manual `networks:`, `container_name:`, and `links:` options without really changing anything else beyond this one host name setting.

Comment: Will try that as well @DavidMaze. If it works it seems to be a more elegant solution for sure. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

it can also work using

```
const redisClient = Redis.createClient({
  url: "redis://yourServiceName:6379",
});
```